# Cannot programmatically delete SVN working copy

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

I am using the [SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) library in an application. As part of my automated integration tests, I create a test repository, check out a working copy, perform some tests, and then delete both the repository and working copy folders.

However, a simple `Directory.Delete(workingCopyPath, true);` always yields an `UnauthorizedAccessException` with the message "*Access to the path 'entries' is denied.*". I can reproduce the error with this code:

```
     using (var svnClient = new SvnClient())
     {
        svnClient.CheckOut(
           new SvnUriTarget(new Uri(repositoryPath)), workingCopyPath);
     }
     Directory.Delete(workingCopyPath, true);
```

This error still occurs if I

- try to delete a working copy created
  by a *previous* run of the integration
  tests
- `Thread.Sleep` a few seconds before
  trying to delete

If I use explorer to manually delete the temporary working copy, I don't get any error.

What is going wrong here? What is the proper way to programmatically delete a subversion working copy?

Comment: Probably one of your integration automated test processes has its current directory set to a directory within the working copy, or is still using a file in the copy.

Comment: No, that's why I mention that I also can't delete working copies created by a *previous* run. The processes of the previous run is no longer running, so I'd say it cannot keep any resources locked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out `Directory.Delete` refuses to delete read-only files.

I now use this method to delete directories:

```
private void DeleteDirectory(string path)
{
   var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
   DisableReadOnly(directory);
   directory.Delete(true);
}

private void DisableReadOnly(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
   foreach (var file in directory.GetFiles())
   {
      if (file.IsReadOnly)
         file.IsReadOnly = false;
   }
   foreach (var subdirectory in directory.GetDirectories())
   {
      DisableReadOnly(subdirectory);
   }
}
```

Comment: That way should work pretty well yeah. You should be able to accept your own answer by the way.